# Laravel recursive event on deleted model not triggering

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have a tree model structure.

I am trying to delete the parent and all descendants should be deleted using the dispatched `deleted` event.

I am also trying to delete all the images, of all the descendants nodes.

I am using a MongoDb ext, a Treetrait, as you can see.

I have logged some messages, in order to see if the dispatched event gets called multiple times, but it gets called only once, while deleting the parent model.

I have the feeling that the dispatched `deleted` event does not get triggered because of the `mass` delete event.

Has anyone encountered something like this?

I am using the ext `https://github.com/beyondlex/mongotree`
and which uses the ext `https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset`

**This is the model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Model;
use Lex\Mongotree\TreeTrait;

class Department extends Model
{
    use TreeTrait;

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'deleted' => \App\Events\DepartmentDeleted::class,
    ];

}
```

**This is the the event:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Department;

class DepartmentDeleted
{

    public $department;

    public function __construct(Department $department)
    {
        $this->$department = $department;

        \Log::debug(json_encode($department->getAttributes()));

        $destination_path = public_path('/images/');

        if (
            $department->image['en'] != ''
            &&
            file_exists($destination_path . $department->image['en'])
        ) {
            \Log::debug('deleting file en' . $department->image['en']);
            unlink($destination_path . $department->image['en']);
        }

        if (
            $department->image['ar'] != ''
            &&
            file_exists($destination_path . $department->image['ar'])
        ) {
            \Log::debug('deleting file ar' . $department->image['ar']);
            unlink($destination_path . $department->image['ar']);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you have reason to believe that the deleted event should be triggered on all descendant models and it currently isn't then this sounds like a bug in the library you're using. Maybe raise case on their github.

Comment: Mass deletes and mass updates will not fire any model events for the models that are deleted / updated. How are you deleting the descendants?

Comment: For some reason, the delete event gets triggered once, and then, the TreeTrait takes over and does the recursive deletion; And that's it, the delete event does not trigger anymore;